# Derive the equations of motion and determine whether angular momentum is conserved..

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, applications

Suppose that the gravitational force is not given by the inverse-square law, and instead is
$$ F_{grav}=\left(\frac{A}{r^{2}}+\frac{B}{r^{4}}\right)\hat{r}, $$
where A and B are real constants. Derive the equations of motion and determine whether angular momentum is conserved. By using the substitution $r = 1/u$, transform the radial component of the equations of motion into a differential equation for $u$ as a function of the angular coordinate $\theta$. Determine for what values of $A$, $B$, and
integration constants stationary solutions exist and whether they are stable.

I have found the differential equation for $U$, however I don't understand how one can determine the values of $A$, $B$ and the integration constants.

The differential equation is
$$ \frac{d^2u}{d^2\theta} + u = - A/h^2 - Bu^2/h^2 ,$$
where $A$, $B$ and $h$ are constants.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I recommend formatting *all* of the formulas, not just the one for the gravitational force.

Comment: I'm new to this page so I'm not great at editing, sorry.

Comment: I assumed you knew how because the first formula is already perfectly formatted. Otherwise I would have linked to https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Looks better, thank you.